# MySQL: order by and limit gives wrong result

Tags: sql, mysql

MySQL ver 5.1.26

I'm getting the wrong result with a select that has where, order by and limit clauses.
It's only a problem when the order by uses the id column.

I saw the MySQL manual for [LIMIT Optimization](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/limit-optimization.html)

My guess from reading the manual is that there is some problem with the index on the primary key, id. But I don't know where I should go from here...

**Question: what should I do to best solve the problem?**

```
Works correctly:
mysql> SELECT id, created_at FROM billing_invoices 
       WHERE (billing_invoices.account_id = 5) ORDER BY id DESC ;
+------+---------------------+
| id   | created_at          |
+------+---------------------+
| 1336 | 2010-05-14 08:05:25 |
| 1334 | 2010-05-06 08:05:25 |
| 1331 | 2010-05-05 23:18:11 |
+------+---------------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)

WRONG result when limit added! Should be the first row, id - 1336
mysql> SELECT id, created_at FROM billing_invoices 
       WHERE (billing_invoices.account_id = 5) ORDER BY id DESC limit 1;
+------+---------------------+
| id   | created_at          |
+------+---------------------+
| 1331 | 2010-05-05 23:18:11 |
+------+---------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

Works correctly:
mysql> SELECT id, created_at FROM billing_invoices 
       WHERE (billing_invoices.account_id = 5) ORDER BY created_at DESC ; 
+------+---------------------+
| id   | created_at          |
+------+---------------------+
| 1336 | 2010-05-14 08:05:25 |
| 1334 | 2010-05-06 08:05:25 |
| 1331 | 2010-05-05 23:18:11 |
+------+---------------------+
3 rows in set (0.01 sec)

Works correctly with limit:
mysql> SELECT id, created_at FROM billing_invoices 
       WHERE (billing_invoices.account_id = 5) ORDER BY created_at DESC limit 1;
+------+---------------------+
| id   | created_at          |
+------+---------------------+
| 1336 | 2010-05-14 08:05:25 |
+------+---------------------+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)

Additional info:
explain SELECT id, created_at FROM billing_invoices WHERE (billing_invoices.account_id = 5) ORDER BY id DESC limit 1;
+----+-------------+------------------+-------+--------------------------------------+--------------------------------------+---------+------+------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table            | type  | possible_keys                        | key                                  | key_len | ref  | rows | Extra       |
+----+-------------+------------------+-------+--------------------------------------+--------------------------------------+---------+------+------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | billing_invoices | range | index_billing_invoices_on_account_id | index_billing_invoices_on_account_id | 4       | NULL |    3 | Using where |
+----+-------------+------------------+-------+--------------------------------------+--------------------------------------+---------+------+------+-------------+
```

Added  SHOW CREATE TABLE billing_invoices result:

```
Table -- billing_invoices
Create Table --
CREATE TABLE `billing_invoices` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `account_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `invoice_date` date NOT NULL,
  `prior_invoice_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `closing_balance` decimal(8,2) NOT NULL,
  `note` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `monthly_invoice` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `created_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `index_billing_invoices_on_account_id` (`account_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1337 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci
```

Added more:

I now see that on my development machine, everything is working correctly. That machine has version  VERSION() of 5.1.26-rc-log

On my *production* machine, where the problem is, I see that VERSION() returns 5.1.26-rc-percona-log

So at this point, I'm thinking the problem is with the percona software?

Added more:

At this point, I'm going to consider it a bug in the Percona InnoDB driver. I've put a [question to their forum](http://forum.percona.com/index.php/t/1446/). As an immediate work-around, I'm going to order by created_at. I will also investigate upgrading the db on my system and see if that helps.

My thanks to Rabbott and mdma for their help. I also appreciate the help that I'm not doing something silly, this really is a problem.

Comment: Please include the results of the following query in your question: `SHOW CREATE TABLE billing_invoices;`.

Comment: Very strange. I tested a similar query on my mysql server and it works just find when i use order by primary_id DESC limit 1  ... my primary id is a autogenerated int... seems like a bug on your server...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could be this bug that was never resolved for your updated version? http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=31001

I am running 5.1.42 locally. I copy and pasted your queries from above and am getting all the correct results.. Whether it be the bug mentioned above or not, it sounds like a bug, and it appears to have been fixed in a more recent release than yours..

Comment: I believe the change in ordering is intentional - since both id and created_at represent equivalent orderings, then changing the ORDEY BE column between these two shouldn't affect the result (unless there is some special behaviour the id column.)

Comment: @Rabbott I know I'm ordering by id in one, created_at in another --that's my point, the limit 1 result for id order is wrong, for created_at is right...

Comment: And what happens when you use my suggestion, just for a datapoint to help determine if it a column type/index issue..

Comment: @Rabbott, I did include your suggestion in the original posting. There are 4 queries, two pairs of queries. The second query, in the first pair, does not work as expected. The second pair does work as expected.

Comment: I am running version: 5.1.42, I just copy and pasted your create table statement, and ran the queries, I am getting the correct result for each one. Can you update MySQL and see what happens? This could be a bug..

Comment: @Rabbott, thank you for finding that bug report. I had found an older one. Unfortunately, when I followed the steps to reproduce the bug, the problem was **not** shown. So apparently I don't have that specific bug.

Comment: I'm now also thinking it is a bug in the MySQL InnoDB driver from Percona. NB, I'm not using their latest. I will upgrade, but it will take some time since it is the production server...

Answer (score 3):

Seems peculiar, maybe a bug? As a workarount maybe you can make the selection explicit - use a subquery to select the MAX(id) and filter on that in a WHERE clause. E.g.

```
SELECT id, created_at FROM billing_invoices 
   WHERE id IN (SELECT MAX(id) FROM billing_invoices WHERE account_id=5)
```

Comment: Just tried it and your query worked, giving id 1336. But the query is created by Rails, so I really need to get at the underlying problem with the db.

Comment: Like the other posters have noted, it sounds like a bug. As you are using a fairly old version, so I'd upgrade before trying anything else.

Answer (score 1):

From here,

[Bug Details](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=37830)

It seems it was fixed in 5.1.28 :

[22 Jul 2008 20:34] Bugs System

Pushed into `5.1.28`

However, I'm noticing the same problem in my version: `5.1.41-3ubuntu12.8`